# post hoc correlation

Tags: correlation, post-hoc, methodology

I’ve got assigned a project which needs to compare two data sets (from real world and laboratory environments). I have the data from the previously done real world observation but I still have to do the lab research. The results from the real world is known.

I don’t need to show any causal relationship between the real world and the laboratory setup, but to see if the behavior is similar to the real world and some parameters change in the similar directions.

What I am concerned about is that such setup will not be perfect from the methodological point of view. I have read about p-hacking and post hoc experiments but would my intention be considered p-hacking if I want to see whether to data sets correlate without any intention in stating the causality?

Thanks

PS. was removed from stack exchange academia because somebody thought it is too much stats in my question..

Comment: A correlation statistic is an effect size; I don't see how there would be p-value hacking involved. Regardless, you should know that with anything involving p-values, the larger your data set, the more likely it will be that you'll see a low p-value without necessarily doing any "hacking". That's why you should always report the effect size.

Comment: Also, I don't think you can use "causal" in this scenario. Just correlation.